# Find elememts of first array in the second array and grep the lines matched with those of first array elements

Tags: regex, perl, perl-data-structures

I have two arrays.One of them has just strings and the other has lines matching the strings at random places. How can I grep the matched lines of second array with the elements of first array? 
**Input_1:**

```
cpu
soc
disk
mobile
processor
etc..
```

**Input 2:**

```
The cpu does all the important processings in a system.
It needs to be improved for processing.
There is also an SoC which does all the processing in a chip.
I think you know well about that.
Now,let us focus on someother thing.
Mobile is one of the world's famous electronic device.
Its impact on growing technology is tremendous.
```

These are my two inputs.Both of them are stored in different arrays.
Now I have to **grep only the lines in input2 which contain elements of input1.**
I tried using the code, But while grep,it is giving me all the lines,but not the ones matched.

```
open(MYFILE,"+<$input_1");
open(MYFILE2,"+<$input_2");
open(WRITE,">wr");

@tap= <MYFILE>;
@sig=<MYFILE2>;

@out=' ';
$count=$#tap;

foreach $i(0 .. $count){
    @out = grep(/$tap[$i]/, @sig);

    print WRITE @out;
}
```

I don't know why I am not able to grep out from the second array? 
Please help me out.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us example input and output.

Comment: "But that's not working" is a terrible description of your problem. What unexpected behaviour are you seeing? What output do you expect to see? Oh, and what is your input?

Comment: Assuming `@tap` is the one with the short strings, and `@sig` has the long lines, your code does the right thing. The result might not look pretty if the lines don't have trailing newlines, but it's definitely producing some output for me.

Comment: Some thoughts on your code. 1/ You don't seem to need the `+` on the file open modes. 2/ You should be using 3-arg `open()` and lexical filehandles (`open my $myfile_fh, '<', $input_1`). 3/ You should check the results from your `open()` calls (`open ... or die $!`). 4/ Why iniitialise `@out` with a single element containing a space? 5/ It's generally easier to iterate over array elements than array indexes (`foreach my $tap (@taps) { @out = grep /$tap/, @sig }; ... }`).

Comment: @DaveCross 6/ make `@out` lexical inside of the loop `foreach my $tap (@taps) { my @out = grep /$tap/, @sig; print ... ; }` 7/ why are you using forward slashes for a numbered list?

Comment: @simbabque: Yeah. I completely missed the lack of lexical variables. And you meant `@out` not `$out` :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your input one (`@tap`) contains linebreaks. That's why you don't get any match. You need to [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) each line after you read it to remove the line breaks.

```
@tap = <MYFILE>;
chomp @tap;
```

Take a look at this:

```
use Data::Dumper;

my @tap = <DATA>;
print Dumper \@tap;

__DATA__
cpu
soc
disk
```

This outputs:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'cpu
',
          'soc
',
          'disk
'
        ];
```

If you add `chomp @tap` you'll get the following instead. The newlines are gone, and the patterns will match.

```
$VAR1 = [
          'cpu',
          'soc',
          'disk'
        ];
```

Comment: Thank you simbabque.. :)

Comment: I have one more doubt here, If I am trying to do the reverse grepping, it is giving me output as the original file without any changes.Is it not possible to reverse grep if variable is present ??

Comment: @Manu I don't understand your question. Can you try to say it with different words please? Maybe give an example?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to grep those lines which donnot have the variable.So, in the above example am trying to use grep(!/ /,@sig).But i am not able to grep those lines.                    foreach $i(0 .. $count){
                                                                       @out = grep(!/$tap[$i]/, @sig);

                                                                          print WRITE @out;
                                                                             }

Comment: @Manu that is the same code you had in the question. Please tell me what's unclear to you now. Your problem was that your input had newline characters. The rest of your code wasn't pretty, but it should work.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to grep those lines which donot have the variable.So, in the above example am trying to use grep(!/ /,@sig).But i am not able to grep those lines.                                                                                foreach $i(0 .. $count){
                                                                       @out = grep(!/$tap[$i]/, @sig);

Comment: @Manu did you understand my answer? You need to `chomp` your `@tap`.

Comment: Yes, I was able to do that Simbabque. We tried to grep those lines with variable.  But now in the same code I want to grep other lines which donot have the variable $tap. So, I am using grep( ! / $tap[$i]/). The output should be lines without the variable.But my output is the original file itself.  Hope you got my question?

Comment: I see @Manu. But are yous till `chomp`ing the input? Doing `grep { !/$tap[$i]/ } @sig` should be fine for that.

Comment: Yes, I am still  chomping the input.. I am trying to grep both with and without variable in the same foreach loop. Can I do that? I have tried in separate loops also,But it isn't giving the required output.Please help.

Comment: Again, I don't understand @Manu. Please show the actual code you're using. You can use backticks `\`` in your comment to format inline-code.

Comment: `foreach $i(0 .. $count){`
   `@out = grep(/$tap[$i]/, @sig);   #grep lines with variable`
`@in= grep(!/$tap[$i]/, @sig);  #grep lines without variable`
    `print WRITE @out; `
`}

Comment: I am grepping one more array, say, @in, which doesn't include the variable $tap;Is this right way to do or not?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to slightly simplify your code by combining all of your regex matches into one. You can also eliminate a lot of your intermediate variables.

```
open my $fh1, '<', $input_1 or die $!;
open my $fh2, '<', $input_2 or die $!;
open my $out_fh, '>', 'wr'  or die $!;

chomp(my @tap = <$fh1>);

my $re = join '|', @tap;  

print $out_fh grep /$re/i, <$fh2>;
```

Note: I've also added a `/i` option to the match operator. This means that the two lines that include "SoC" and "Mobile" will also match.